# How to count the number of the bits in the long long type variables?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to count the bits in the long long type variable. For example,
1100011001 -> 5

In the integer type, I can use

```cpp
a = (a & 0x5555) + ((a & 0xAAAA) >> 1); 
a = (a & 0x3333) + ((a & 0xCCCC) >> 2); 
a = (a & 0x0F0F) + ((a & 0xF0F0) >> 4); 
a = (a & 0x00FF) + ((a & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

but in case of "long long", how to do that?

Comment: `__builtin_popcountll()` if you're using gcc or clang. Probably doesn't count if this is for homework, of course.

Comment: Do you understand how the above works?

Comment: If you understand *why* that works, it shouldn't be that hard to extend it to a wider integer type.

Comment: Or if using a even remotely recent x86 cpu, `_mm_popcnt_u64()` from `<nmmintrin.h>`. Same caveat.

Comment: You're not counting the bits, you're counting the 1's

Comment: Or there's always good old `std::bitset<64> b{yournumber}; auto numbits = b.count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is for 16-bit integers.

To make it work with 32-bit integers, you need to:

- make each literal in it two times wider (while preserving the pattern),
- add one more line of code.

Here's the result:

```
a = (a & 0x55555555) + ((a & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1); 
a = (a & 0x33333333) + ((a & 0xCCCCCCCC) >> 2); 
a = (a & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((a & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4); 
a = (a & 0x00FF00FF) + ((a & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8); 
a = (a & 0x0000FFFF) + ((a & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
```

Then, to make it work with 64-bit integers, you repeat the same procedure:

```
a = (a & 0x5555555555555555) + ((a & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) >> 1); 
...
a = (a & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) + ((a & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16); 
a = (a & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) + ((a & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32);
```